# Issues with google REST api: enum keys returns spurious values

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform

Im trying to write some code to rotate service account keys for integration testing. To this end I have a function that gets all the keys for a test account using the REST api. This involves sending a **GET** request to

`https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + projectName + "/serviceAccounts/" + accountEmail + "/keys"`

The result(s) of this are a JSON string with an array of Map that have

- keyName (project/account/keyId)
- validAfterTime
- validBeforeTime
- keyAlgorithm

the 'before' and 'after' times are Zulu values that seem to indicate valid times for said key.

This is all well and good.. except.. that with every call I seem to get 2 or more entries that are either expired or not valid yet, have a 2 day valid span and don't appear in the google console. Trying to delete one of these returns a

> "code": 400,    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument."

What are these entries? Why are they showing up in this list?

---

#### Edit -

if someone from google happens to wander by this post - there is a doc bug on [this](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys) page. The URL for 'listing service keys' should be a **GET** request and not a **POST** as it currently shows.